# Simple python code error

Tags: python

```
 error: Can't convert int to str implicitely
```

Code:

```
user_name = input("What is your name? ")
print("Hello {}!, this program is going to ask you to type in a series of numbers (all positive integers)" .format(user_name))

total_numbers = input("How many numbers would you like to add")

for i in range(1, total_numbers):
  number = float(input("State a numbers {}: " .format(i)))
  total_numbers += number

  print("Total number: {}" .format(total_numbers))
```

MY TASK IS TO: Ask for the user’s name to be entered. It should be stored in a suitable variable (like `user_name`)
Ask for how many numbers are going to be entered. Store this in a suitable variable too. (like “`num_values`”)
Then get each of the numbers entered.
You will need to have some way of keeping a total of all of the numbers and at the end, once all numbers have been entered, you need to print out something like..

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in lines -

```
total_numbers = input("How many numbers would you like to add")
for i in range(1, total_numbers):
    number = float(input("State a numbers {}: " .format(i)))
    total_numbers += number
```

You have to convert `total_numbers` to `int` to use in `range` function. Like -

```
total_numbers = int(input("How many numbers would you like to add"))
for i in range(1, total_numbers):
    number = float(input("State a numbers {}: " .format(i)))
    total_numbers += number
```

Also, I see that you are adding numbers to `total_numbers` inside the loop itself, maybe you instead want to create a new variable , initilize with 0 and add to it instead, Increasing `total_numbers` itself would give you unexpected results.

Code would be -

```
total_numbers = int(input("How many numbers would you like to add"))
total = 0.0
for i in range(1, total_numbers):
    number = float(input("State a numbers {}: " .format(i)))
    total += number
print("Total number: {}" .format(total))
```

Comment: Now it comes up with TypeError: Can't convert float to str implicitely

this is the code at the moment: user_name = input("What is your name? ")
print("Hello {}!, this program is going to ask you to type in a series of numbers (all positive integers)" .format(user_name))

total_numbers = input("How many numbers would you like to add")

for i in range(1, int(total_numbers)):
  number = float(input("State a numbers {}" .format(i)))
  total_numbers += number
  
  print("Total number: {}" .format(total_numbers))